# Horizontal Calendar in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, nscalendar

I have used `UIDatePicker` as native control and also used libraries mentioned over **Stackoverflow** and **github**. But i want to have a calendar view , horizontally scrolling days in a row like in image.

Please share your ideas/logic about what are possible solutions to achieve this functionality. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use library that is most closest to functionality you required and can customize its appearance as per you need.

https://github.com/CapitalGene/objc-CGCalendarView

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Khawar but i have imported your given github project but not able to see text date http://imgur.com/p3LT4oS please check this image and please tell me how can i see text of date .

Comment: @Michel Check this issue here:
https://github.com/CapitalGene/objc-CGCalendarView/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a perfect time for a horizontal collection view. Just have some sort of calendar datasource and you are good to go. Should be able to use the flow layout and set the direction to horizontal and kapow, done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .  i have given it thought but problem remain same for getting NSCalendar items as datasource. Is there any built in functionality in NSDatePicker to get all the dates as it does in native picker?Plus shades and curl on side dates are also required.